# How read value from properties file and put into JSON file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have liquibase.json file. Threa are:

```
"runningAs": {
            "username": "Programer200"
          }
```

I try to creat custom property:

```
liquibaseuser=root
```

Is it possible put value of liquibaseuser to liquibase.json ?

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the json to a model and change the values.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // 1 read property
        String property = "root";
        // 2 read json
        String json = "{\"username\": \"Programer200\"}";
        // 3 map json to model
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyModel jsonObject = mapper.readValue(json, MyModel.class);
        // 4 change variables
        jsonObject.username = property;
        System.out.println(mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(jsonObject));
    }
}


class MyModel
{
    public String username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the below library for the data access.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency
```

After access the data you can modify the Json String. But firstly you require to get the data like below.

```
String user = JsonPath.read(json, "$.runningAs.username");

System.out.println(user);
```

In your quandary, it seem's like you require key and value, then you can utilize the map.